# RVO and NRVO optimisations + C++11 move operator

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvo, nrvo

I am trying to figure out how RVO and NRVO work along with the new C++11 move operators.
I have drafted a dummy class with a few examples.

EDIT: Only most important part of the code is shown.

Full source code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/ricleal/7772082).

I have two functions that get the class as reference and return either a value or a reference:

```
VOpt& fChangeClassRetRef(VOpt &m) {
    m.setX(21);
    return m;
}

VOpt fChangeClassRetValue(VOpt &m) {
    m.setX(21);
    return m;
}
```

When I call these functions I have as output the following:

```
VOpt &m14 = fChangeClassRetRef(m13);

m14 = fChangeClassRetRef(m11);
     -> Copy Assignment Operator

m14 = fChangeClassRetValue(m11);
     -> Copy Constructor
     -> C++11 Move Operator
```

When an lvalue reference is used no copy constructors are invoked. Otherwise, those functions (that receive a reference as parameter) still call copy constructors.

Is this feature compiler dependent? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Just to get it out of the way, there is no move operator. You might mean the move assignment operator, but there's no move operator in general.

Comment: The concepts are orthogonal. If there is RVO or NRVO, there is no scope for moving anything.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Do you by any chance know the answer to the question? Are these calls to the copy constructors compiler dependent?

Comment: There's a LOT of code here - it would be nice to simplify the program just to the cases that confuse you, and to state the expected behavior of those cases.

Comment: @Casey : Just edited the question as suggested.

Comment: The more interesting case is if you remove all references (pass m by value, return by value). Then C++03 allows copy elision (though no compiler does it), but C++11 doesn't. It does use the move constructor though.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Erm, what? C++11 allows copy elision just the same.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: What on earth are you talking about? C++11 did not forbid any copy elision that was legal in C++03. In fact, the definition of when the compiler can perform an implicit move is when the copy can be legally elided.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1148

Answer (score 3):

```
m14 = fChangeClassRetRef(m11);
     -> Copy Assignment Operator
```

The function returns a reference (lvalue), it cannot do move-assignment as the argument is not an rvalue.

```
m14 = fChangeClassRetValue(m11);
     -> Copy Constructor
     -> C++11 Move Operator
```

The copy constructor is triggered internally to create the returned value. It must be a copy constructor and not a move constructor as the argument is a reference (lvalue). The assignment of the returned value to `m14` uses the move assignment operator as the argument is an rvalue.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
// Change the value of the class, return ref!
VOpt& fChangeClassRetRef(VOpt &m) {
    m.setX(21);
    return m; //#1
}
```

which was used this way:

```
// VOpt m11;
VOpt m12 = fChangeClassRetRef(m11); // #2
```

Let's analyse: `#1` returns the name of an argument (not a local variable), so neither RVO nor NRVO applies here. Now `fChangeClassRetRef` returns a reference to wherever `m` is bound to, which, in #2 is `m11`. Therefore, we're initializing `m12` with an lvalue reference to `m11`. In this case he compiler can't call the move constructor because it takes an rvalue and, as we have just seen, you are providing an lvalue. The copy constructor gets called.

The other case is similar. You have

```
VOpt fChangeClassRetValue(VOpt &m) {
    m.setX(21);
    return m;
}
```

which is called this way:

```
// VOpt m13; 
VOpt &m14 = fChangeClassRetRef(m13);
```

As above, there's no RVO neither NRVO here because you're returning the name of an argument.

The function returns by value and you're returning an lvalue. (In some circunstances compilers are allowed to treat the returning lvalue as if it was an rvalue but not in this case.) Hence the move constructor cannot be called and the copy constructor is invoked.